# Configuring Tomato Web Usage log

Tags: router, logging, tomato

I am running Linksys E2000 with TomatoUSB (on the 2nd floor) as a "switch" connected to my main router (d-link 655 with stock firmware on the 1st floor, wireless disabled). All my computers are wired connected to the E2000 and there are some devices (iPod, phones, tab) connected wirelessly. The firmware I am using is the one specificly for E2000 (ver 1.28 beta).

I want to monitor the web usage (not bandwidth) - ip/url people visited etc. I found the web usage configuration, but it's not logging anything. I have left it on for several days and knowing for sure that the computers/devices have been used to browse the web etc - but the "Web Usage" log remains empty.

Is there anything special that I need to configure beyond the loggin config or is it not possible to log web-usage when it's not used as the main router?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you've got it set up as a "switch," but I had the same problem with a VLAN version of Toastman's build of v1.28.7636, set up as a second router.  Web Monitor was enabled, but nothing was showing up. Also wasn't showing IP Traffic either, that looked like it could have been related to using a non-192.168.1.x network, since the IP Traffic webpages always show 192.168.1.x no matter the WAN or LAN settings.

I did try wiping the NVRAM and rebooting, etc, but it didn't work. Trying a different version, the Non-VLAN version, same build, did work. Still no IP Traffic, but good 'nuf. So possibly a bug in some versions? Try a different version, or a newer or older build?